# IllegalStateException creating bean 'metricsConfiguration' while triying to run JHipster App on Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, jhipster

I've built a simple JHipster application with these settings on `.yo-rc.json`:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.jhtest",
      "nativeLanguage": "es"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "5.5.0",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "jhTest",
    "packageName": "com.jhtest",
    "packageFolder": "com/jhtest",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "oracle",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "...",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "es",
    "languages": [
      "es",
      "en"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've added `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` to pom.xml in prod profile:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and a `ServletInitializer` class:

```
    package com.jhtest;

    import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

    public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(JhTestApp.class);
        }
    }
```

I've run `mvnw -Pprod package` in order to package the project as a .war file. I've tried to run `jh-test.war.original` (this one recommended by JHipster documentation) on Tomcat (v8.5).

During the start of Tomcat I get that error:

```
2018-11-05 12:10:06.657  WARN 2124 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.DelegatingMetricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setMetricsConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot use setMetricsTrackerFactory() and setMetricRegistry() together
2018-11-05 12:10:06.683 ERROR 2124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.DelegatingMetricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setMetricsConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot use setMetricsTrackerFactory() and setMetricRegistry() together
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:666)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)

[...]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot use setMetricsTrackerFactory() and setMetricRegistry() together
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setMetricsTrackerFactory(HikariConfig.java:710)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.setMetricsTrackerFactory(HikariDataSource.java:255)
at com.jhtest.config.MetricsConfiguration.init(MetricsConfiguration.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

[...]
```

Comment: You got any solution for this?